# How can I use ffmpeg to convert from mp4 to avi for use in Davinci Resolve without massive increase in filesize?

Tags: ffmpeg, codecs, davinci-resolve

I have an mp4 file that I'd like to edit within Davinci Resolve.
Due to licensing issues,  the free version of Resolve cannot edit videos that are encoded using h.264.

I'd like to use ffmpeg.

I attempted to convert the video from mp4 to a mov file with the video re-encoded to the prores format.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v prores_ks -profile:v 1 out.mov
```

This suceeded somewhat: but the video blew out in size from 80M to nearly 3G. Additionally, all sound was removed from the output video.

I'd like to convert my video so that it can be used in the free version of Davinci Resolve. I'd also like to keep the sound. I'd also like to keep a filesize that isn't massive when compared to the size of the original file.

Comment: Could you post the FFmpeg command as well as the complete, uncut terminal output as an edit in your question?

Comment: My question already includes the ffmpeg command. The uncut terminal output is much much too large to paste into the question.

Comment: Unless there are error messages the terminal output will be fine here. If you are worried use a Pastebin.